# Can I receive text messages when mobile data turned off

Tags: notifications, sms, mms

If I have my mobile data function turned off, will I be able to receive text messages?  If so, how can I retrieve them?

Answer (score 1):

SMS messages are not normally sent over mobile data.  You should automatically receive them, exactly like normal.

Even MMS messages typically have their own APN set up so that they can be received without other data services.